# PL/SQL counting by looping?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have an assignment asking me to rewrite this PL/SQL code I wrote for a previous assignment:

```
DECLARE
    -- Variables used to count a, b, c, d, and f grades:
    na integer := 0;
    nb integer := 0;
    nc integer := 0;
    nd integer := 0;
    nf integer := 0;
BEGIN
    select count(*) into na
    from   gradeReport1
    where  grade = 'A';

    select count(*) into nb
    from   gradeReport1
    where  grade = 'B';

    select count(*) into nc
    from   gradeReport1
    where  grade = 'C';

    select count(*) into nd
    from   gradeReport1
    where  grade = 'D';

    select count(*) into nf
    from   gradeReport1
    where  grade = 'F';

    if na > 0 then
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('There are total ' || na || ' A''s');
    else
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('There are no As');
    end if;

    if nb > 0 then
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('There are total ' || nb || ' B''s');
    else 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('There are no Bs');
    end if;

    if nc > 0 then
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('There are total ' || nc || ' C''s');
    else
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('There are no Cs');
    end if;

    if nd > 0 then
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('There are total ' || nd || ' D''s');
    else
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('There are no Ds');
    end if;

    if nf > 0 then
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('There are total ' || nf || ' F''s');
    else
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('There are no Fs');
    end if;
END;
```

All it does is search a table I made called gradeReport that stores studentID's and associates them with a grade. The PL/SQL counts all instances of a grade A through F. The question wants me to rewrite this solution using looping and VARRAYS. Could anyone give me a hint to help get the ball rolling for me? I've only been using PL/SQL for a few weeks and don't have much more than a basic understanding of the syntax so I'm completely lost and have no idea where to start.

Not looking for any answers here, just some ideas.

Thank You

Comment: I can see you have plenty of answers below so I won't add to them.  However your approach is definitely going to be quicker than a LOOP.  If this is an academic assignment then fine, but if it's for practical use I would not rewrite the code.

Answer (score 1):

How about starting with the doc. http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/LNPLS/plsql-control-statements.htm#LNPLS004

Comment: Definitely. Thank You!

Comment: Are you specifically required to use varrays? They are not generally useful in PL/SQL, as there are just a functionally crippled version of nested tables with a `limit` clause you don't usually need.

Answer (score 1):

*Edit: as the requirement is specifically for varrays, see replies by AmmoQ and MTO. As they both point out, though, you'd be unlikely to need arrays for this type of task in practice, and even if you did, you would use a [nested table](http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/composites.htm#LNPLS99981) or an [associative array](http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/composites.htm#LNPLS99969) and not a [varray](http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/composites.htm#LNPLS443).*

You'll want a [Cursor FOR loop](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/LNPLS/cursor-FOR-LOOP-statement.htm), along the lines of

```
for r in (
    select grade from gradereport1
)
loop
    ...
end loop;
```

In real code you'd probably make that a `group by` query and have SQL do the counting for you.

Then just conditionally increment the counters in the loop depending in the value of `r.grade`.

You can rationalise all of the `if` statements for reporting the totals by writing a procedure that takes a grade and a total, as the logic is the same for all of them.

```
procedure showgrade
    ( p_grade gradereport1.grade%type
    , p_count integer )
is
begin
    ...
end showgrade;
```

I'll leave the details as an exercise.

Just for fun, here is another approach, using arrays and looping (but not a varray - they really are a bit useless):

```
declare
    type gradereport_tt is table of pls_integer index by gradereport.grade%type;
    gradecounts gradereport_tt;
    g gradereport.grade%type;
begin
    -- Initialise counts:
    gradecounts('A') := 0;
    gradecounts('B') := 0;
    gradecounts('C') := 0;
    gradecounts('D') := 0;
    gradecounts('E') := 0;
    gradecounts('F') := 0;

    -- Count grades:
    for r in (
        select grade from gradereport
    )
    loop
        gradecounts(r.grade) := gradecounts(r.grade) +1;
    end loop;

    -- Report counts:
    g := gradecounts.first;

    while g is not null loop
        dbms_output.put_line(g || ': ' || gradecounts(g));
        g := gradecounts.next(g);
    end loop;
end;
```

btw there is no need to put brackets after `if` as in some other languages, unless the condition contains a mixture of `and` and `or` conditions that need separating.

There is also no need to write anything in uppercase. It's quite common and [Steven Feuerstein](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/index-087690.html) does it all the time, but they had this debate in the HTML/CSS world and settled on lowercase for readability. And if you are going to have an uppercase rule, at least use it consistently. Your code example has `end if;` but `END;` not to mention `Select` (which I've fixed). Some people seem to be able to read code like this without it driving them nuts, but I'm afraid I'm not one of them.

Comment: +1 for "There is also no need to write anything in uppercase." I had a coworker who did that all the time, writing almost everything in uppercase, and eventually I wrote a utility that undoes this rubbish without breaking literal text, comments etc.

Comment: Thanks :) I expect Steven will be along in a minute to explain why it's OK to have your code look like COBOL-77 if it's PL/SQL but not for any other language.

Comment: The similarity with COBOL is my main reason to avoid uppercase, too

Comment: I'd just settled on using lowercase for everything, but the company I'm now at have a standard that involves uppercase for keywords etc. \*sigh\*

Comment: The OP states: `The question wants me to rewrite this solution using looping and VARRAYS.`Using a cursor does not meet this requirement.

Comment: @MT0 that's a good point. I suppose he could use `bulk collect`. I might update my answer.

Comment: @ammoQ then you won't mind me editing your answer and lowercasing it?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson no problem, do it please!

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE
  -- Need to ensure the array size will hold all the grades
  TYPE grade_tab IS VARRAY(200) OF gradeReport1.grade%TYPE;

  -- variable used to store the grades:
  t_grades grade_tab;

  -- Variables used to count a, b, c, d, and f grades:
  na INTEGER;
  nb INTEGER;
  nc INTEGER;
  nd INTEGER;
  nf INTEGER;
BEGIN
  -- Store the grades in an array:
  SELECT grade
  BULK COLLECT INTO t_grades
  FROM   gradeReport1
  WHERE  grade IN ( 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F' );

  -- Loop through the grades and count how many of each:
  FOR i IN 1 .. t_grades.COUNT LOOP
    IF    t_grades(i) = 'A' THEN na := na + 1;
    ELSIF t_grades(i) = 'B' THEN nb := nb + 1;
    ELSIF t_grades(i) = 'C' THEN nc := nc + 1;
    ELSIF t_grades(i) = 'D' THEN nd := nd + 1;
    ELSIF t_grades(i) = 'F' THEN nf := nf + 1;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  -- Output grade counts
END;
/
```

However, a much simpler solution would be to do the counting in a single SQL query (although this doesn't meet the assessment's requirements of using a `VARRAY`):

```
DECLARE
  -- Variables used to count a, b, c, d, and f grades:
  na INTEGER;
  nb INTEGER;
  nc INTEGER;
  nd INTEGER;
  nf INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT( CASE grade WHEN 'A' THEN 1 END ),
         COUNT( CASE grade WHEN 'B' THEN 1 END ),
         COUNT( CASE grade WHEN 'C' THEN 1 END ),
         COUNT( CASE grade WHEN 'D' THEN 1 END ),
         COUNT( CASE grade WHEN 'F' THEN 1 END )
  INTO   na,
         nb,
         nc,
         nd,
         nf
  FROM   gradeReport1;

  -- Output grade counts...
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
set SERVEROUTPUT ON
declare
type number_array is VARRAY(5) OF integer;
total integer :=0;
i number :=1;
begin
    numbers :=number_array(14,45,67,89,21);
    arr_size := numbers.count;
    
    FOR i in 1..arr_size loop
    total :=total+numbers(i);
 end loop;
 dbms_output.put_line('total-' || total);
end;
```

here I want to count the number_array elements, but I can't get the correct answers. what is the problem with this?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31010595)

Answer (score 0):

A solution using VARRAYs could look like that:

```
DECLARE 
   type chararray IS VARRAY(6) OF CHAR(1); 
   type numarray IS VARRAY(6) OF INTEGER; 
   grades chararray; 
   cnt  numarray; 
BEGIN 
   select grade, count(*) 
     bulk collect into grades, cnt
     from gradeReport1
     group by grade
     order by grade;

   for i in 1..grades.count loop
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('There are total ' || cnt(i) || ' ' ||grades(i)||'s');
   end loop;
END; 
/
```

But honestly, it's pointless to use VARRAYs in that case. Just use a cursor loop:

```
BEGIN 
   for c in ( select grade, count(*) cnt 
                from gradeReport1
                group by grade
                order by grade ) loop    
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('There are total ' || c.cnt || ' ' ||c.grade||'s');
   end loop;
END; 
/
```

Finding the missing marks (those with a count of 0) is a bit more difficult, though.